# Blur a samplerExternalOES texture in a fragment shader

Tags: android, opengl-es, glsl, shader

I'm running a video on a OpenGL texture and applying multiple image filters to it using a fragment shader.

Code snippet from the shader:

```
 private static final String fragmentShaderCode =
        "#extension GL_OES_EGL_image_external : require\n" +
        "precision mediump float;" +
        "uniform samplerExternalOES texture;" +
        "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;" +
...
```

I'd like to also blur this, but I only found examples to blur a **sampler2D** texture, not a **samplerExternalOES** one.

Is it possible to convert from one to the other? Or how would that work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this same as `sampler2D`. You can access texture using `texture2D` function itself. Apply your blurr filter as if it was a normal texture. It should work.